# Open local file Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, filepath

I have a file located on my virtual. and I try to do this:

```
    File file = new File("invoice2.xml");
    if (file.exists()) {
    textview1.setText("file exists");
    }
    else{
    textview1.setText("file dosen't exist");
    }
```

This displays "file dosen't exist". I am using eclipse and according to the DDMS file explorer my "invoice2.xml" file is located in

data/data/invoicing.digital.namespace/files/invoice2.xml

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the "file exists" result? 
thank you

EDIT: this worked File file = new File(MyActivity.this.getFilesDir(), "invoice2.xml");

Comment: if possible better to put that in raw or asset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to read from the root folder. Try this approach:

```
File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + "invoice2.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible better to put that in raw or asset 
or 
file name should be like this 
System.getProperty("filesDir")+File.separator+YOUR_INTERNAL_FILE_NAME

Comment: Thank you, howver I don't want to move the file.